# Type of space in a black hole

Tags: black-holes, spacetime

Outgoing photons that start off outside the Event Horizon can escape

Outgoing photons that are emitted at r = 2M remain at r = 2M forever

Outgoing photons that are emitted at r < 2M fall towards r = 0

What does it mean when someone says that black hole interior and exterior is Minkowski space but event horizon is Schwarzschild solution?

(I heard this on a bus but can't work out what they meant)

Comment: *I read though that the depth of space within a black hole is actually infinite. * Where did you read this, and what is it supposed to mean? Please edit your question to give enough information so that it can actually be answered.

Comment: but my question is purposely general to avoid taking side in singularity versus non-singularity argument. Thank you. I will edit but may take longer time

Comment: @safesphere - https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/7880

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one kind of spacetime. In environments like black hole interiors properties we normally regard as belonging purely to space or time get mixed up.

You are right in that one can measure the circumference of a black hole and get a reasonable result. If you try it around a dense body like a neutron star and then measure how deep a hole to the core is, you will indeed find that [the distance to the centre and interior volume is a bit bigger than expected from the circumference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_Schwarzschild_metric#Volume): there is some stretching of the space near and in heavy masses.

However, black holes do not really have infinite volume. Actually defining a volume of a black hole is surprisingly tricky, since it matters *when* we measure it and across what kind of slice of spacetime (remember, on the inside radial and time coordinates kind of switch meaning). [Christodoulou and Rovelli](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.2854) worked out one approach that gives a surprisingly large, but finite, interior volume of black holes. [Others have extended it to rotating black holes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01907). These volumes are not really what one would observe if one were to dive in, though. In a sense the radial coordinate becomes your time, counting down inexorably toward meeting the singularity, and the time coordinate helps adding volume. So saying the type of space inside is different is not entirely wrong.